# Pandas Boolean indexing with two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes:

```
df1
'A' 'B'
 0   0
 0   2
 1   1
 1   1
 1   3

df2
'ID' 'value'
 0   62
 1   70
 2   76
 3   4674
 4   3746
```

I want to assign `df.value` as a new column `D` to df1, but just when `df.A == 0`.
`df1.B` and `df2.ID` are supposed to be the identifiers.

Example output:

```
df1
'A' 'B' 'D'
 0   0   62
 0   2   76
 1   1   NaN
 1   1   NaN
 1   3   NaN
```

I tried the following:

```
df1['D'][ df1.A == 0 ] = df2['value'][df2.ID == df1.B]
```

However, since df2 and df1 don't have the same length, I get the a ValueError.

```
ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare
```

This is quite certainly due to the boolean indexing in the last part: `[df2.ID == df1.B]`

Does anyone know how to solve the problem without needing to iterate over the dataframe(s)?

Thanks a bunch!

==============

Edit in reply to @EdChum: It worked perfectly with the example data, but I have issues with my real data. df1 is a huge dataset. df2 looks like this:

```
df2
    ID  value
0   1   1.00000
1   2   1.00000
2   3   1.00000
3   4   1.00000
4   5   1.00000
5   6   1.00000
6   7   1.00000
7   8   1.00000
8   9   0.98148
9   10  0.23330
10  11  0.56918
11  12  0.53251
12  13  0.58107
13  14  0.92405
14  15  0.00025
15  16  0.14863
16  17  0.53629
17  18  0.67130
18  19  0.53249
19  20  0.75853
20  21  0.58647
21  22  0.00156
22  23  0.00000
23  24  0.00152
24  25  1.00000
```

After doing the merging, the output is the following: first 133 times 0.98148, then 47 times 0.00025 and then it continues with more sequences of values from df2 until finally a sequence of NaN entries appear...

```
Out[91]: df1
    A   B   D
0   1   3   0.98148
1   0   9   0.98148
2   0   9   0.98148
3   0   7   0.98148
5   1   21  0.98148
7   1   12  0.98148
...     ...     ...     ...
2592    0   2   NaN
2593    1   17  NaN
2594    1   16  NaN
2596    0   17  NaN
2597    0   6   NaN
```

Any idea what might have happened here? They are all int64.

==============

Here are two csv with data that reproduces the problem.

df1:
https://owncloud.tu-berlin.de/public.php?service=files&t=2a7d244f55a5772f16aab364e78d3546

df2:
https://owncloud.tu-berlin.de/public.php?service=files&t=6fa8e0c2de465cb4f8a3f8890c325eac

To reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("../../df1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("../../df2.csv")

df1['D'] = df1[df1.A == 0].merge(df2,left_on='B', right_on='ID', how='left')['value']
```

Comment: Can you post links to the real data, at the moment it's hard to understand what the real problem is here, if not possible then can you post sample data and code that reproduces the problem

Comment: Good idea. I added links to the CSVs of df1 and df2.

Comment: It looks like what you may want to do is `map` the values I can't answer now as I have to go home first but I think something like `df['D'] = df[df.A==0]['B'].map(df1.set_index('ID')['value'])` may work, this is some ad hoc code that may not work, I can't test until I get home

Comment: That works! A neat solution - would have never thought of it. **Thanks a lot!** I'm still not clear **why the other solution didn't work**, though. I'll leave the data online for a while in case someone wants to have a look into it.

Comment: Will you add this to your answer? I'll be more than happy to accept it. :)

Comment: I've added the update, if I get time I'll look at your data also

Comment: Hi, I looked at your data and figured out the error, on your toy example it worked fine because the `NaN` values appeared at the end, unfortunately this is not what your real data looked like so you need to mask the left hand side also so the following worked: `df1.loc[df1.A==0, 'D'] = df1[df1.A == 0].merge(df2,left_on='B', right_on='ID', how='left')['value']` see my updated answer

Comment: Sweet. So generally it's better to use your second or third solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: yes, that way will always work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly tricky this one, there are 2 steps here, first is to select only the rows in df where 'A' is 0, then merge to this the other df where 'B' and 'ID' match but perform a 'left' merge, then select the 'value' column from this and assign to the df:

```
In [142]:

df['D'] = df[df.A == 0].merge(df1, left_on='B',right_on='ID', how='left')['value']
df
Out[142]:
   A  B   D
0  0  0  62
1  0  2  76
2  1  1 NaN
3  1  1 NaN
4  1  3 NaN
```

Breaking this down will show what is happening:

```
In [143]:
# boolean mask on condition
df[df.A == 0]
Out[143]:
   A  B   D
0  0  0  62
1  0  2  76
In [144]:
# merge using 'B' and 'ID' columns
df[df.A == 0].merge(df1, left_on='B',right_on='ID', how='left')
Out[144]:
   A  B   D  ID  value
0  0  0  62   0     62
1  0  2  76   2     76
```

After all the above you can then assign directly:

```
df['D'] = df[df.A == 0].merge(df1, left_on='B',right_on='ID', how='left')['value']
```

This works as it will align with the left hand side idnex so any missing values will automatically be assigned `NaN`

**EDIT**

Another method and one that seems to work for your real data is to use `map` to perform the lookup for you, `map` accepts a dict or series as a param and will lookup the corresponding value, in this case you need to set the index to 'ID' column, this reduces your df to one with just the 'Value' column:

```
df['D'] = df[df.A==0]['B'].map(df1.set_index('ID')['value'])
```

So the above performs boolean indexing as before and then calls `map` on the 'B' column and looksup the corresponding 'Value' in the other df after we set the index on 'ID'.

**Update**

I looked at your data and my first method and I can see why this fails, the alignment to the left hand side df fails so you get 1192 values in a continuous row and then the rest of the rows are `NaN` up to row 2500.

What does work is if you apply the same mask to the left hand side like so:

```
df1.loc[df1.A==0, 'D'] = df1[df1.A == 0].merge(df2,left_on='B', right_on='ID', how='left')['value']
```

So this masks the rows on the left hand side correctly and assigns the result of the merge

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @EdChum. This works like a charm for this data example. I have issues with my real data though. For some reason, it does something like [edit: see question]